# Rails server giving Readline support error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, readline

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to start the RoR server. But when I run the command `rails server` it gives me the following error:

```
Sorry, you can't use byebug without Readline. To solve this, you need to
    rebuild Ruby with Readline support. If using Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get
    install libreadline-dev` and then reinstall your Ruby.
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/abraar/ror/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of     APP_PATH     was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

I'm using rbenv with Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.1
I tried following the instructions on this blog post http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby/readline-in-ruby-with-rbenv/ but it's not working.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is a gem used for debugging.

The new app generator for rails includes it by default in the development & test environments with the [following lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/45786be516e13d55a1fca9a4abaddd5781209103/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile#L24-L27):

```
group :development, :test do
<% if RUBY_ENGINE == 'ruby' -%>
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
```

I don't think it is important for a newcomer to be able to use it. I would recommend commenting out that line in the Gemfile, run `bundle install` and continue with your rails learning adventure.

Comment: Great! My Rails server is up and running now... Your solution is working. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. You can come back to `byebug` / other options for debugging in a rails app later on when you need it.

Comment: Its working in my case as well. But I want to know why it is not working before as I have done what error says. I have installed the required package and then reinstalled ruby using 'rbenv' and by compiling from source as well but nothing works for me.

Comment: this is not a solution to problem and why would beginner rails developer wouldn't need debugging, what if he comes from other language and is not a total newbie.

Comment: Agreed with prior comment.  Not a solution.  And, `byebug` is VERY useful, especially for beginners!

Answer (score 17):

To fix this (for OSX, tested on Sierra), run following command in your shell -

`ln -s  /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib  /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

Comment: Thank you! I read about Zero's answer, but this one did the trick for me

Comment: I changed libreadline.6.dylib with libreadline.7.dylib and it did the trick for me

Answer (score 8):

### July 2019 on Mac

I faced this same issue on my machine & running the following command solved it, note that even if you have version 8 of readline you still need to link to version 7 as shown:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by (commands for mac with homebrew and rbenv):

- installing readline `brew install readline`
- reinstalling / recompiling ruby `rbenv install 2.3.1`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the following error:

```
Sorry, you can't use byebug without Readline
```

Reinstalling ruby resolved this for me (using rvm):

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.5
```

You can replace ruby version ie, 2.1.5 with the one you want to reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the development group of gem.

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/289#issuecomment-251383465

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by follwing way

```
brew unlink readline 
brew link readline --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a hurry,

Open your byebug's history.rb

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails/gems/byebug-9.0.5/lib/byebug/history.rb
```

and comment out the following line,

```
require 'readline'
```

But, It is recommended to use byebug to debug.